# Update plist to support Retina displays in my game

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, game-engine, retina-display, texturepacker

I am working on a game, I am trying to make it support retina devices, I have placed the -hd images/sprite sheets. But I don't have  texture packer project file. Can I edit the plist file for -hd images?

Comment: Yes you can but you don't want to do that. It's terribly tedious and error prone to do this manually, you could waste days trying to get this done and done right. Get ahold of the .tps file or extract the original images from the atlas (if you don't have them available separately) and recreate the atlases with TP.

Comment: Thanks LearnCocos2D for your response, I will give it a try.